# Github Pages adding avatar image to source

Tags: github-pages, google-pagespeed

I have been trying to increase the Google Page Speed rankings of my Github Pages site, but I am now getting these avatar images added to the source - and Google Page Speed is penalising me for them.

Does anybody know if there is a Github setting to disable this?

https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/22068367?v=3&s=64
https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/22068367?v=3&s=460

[image: Google Page Speed]

Comment: Can you send a link to the page?

Comment: @NooBskie https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Farimolzer.com&tab=desktop Here you go buddy

Comment: It appears to be inconsistent though, sometimes its in the page speed results, sometimes its not. 

My score is pretty good, but I'd love a 100/100 if thats even possible

Comment: yea im not seeing it on my side

Comment: Can you post an example GitHub page that loads these avatars? (Not your full page, just [a small example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.)